# How to find a value for a particular column by looking into the same table

Tags: hive, hiveql

In Hive, I have a table let's keep it us table A which contains columns like sk,control_number and original_control_number.

Example for source:
[image]

I want to populate the so related to the original_control_number as adjusted_sk in the target table

Result which I want to populate in target:

[image]

Here the adjusted_sk is populated as when the original_control_number and  control_number is same then it should be NULL and for the 2nd record I have to return the sk values of original_control_number by assuming it has control_number (I have to see what is the sk related to the original_control_number in source)

can anyone suggest any ways to achieve this results . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One option is a left join:

```
select 
    t.*,
    t1.sk adjusted_sk
from tablea t
left join tablea t1
    on  t1.control_number = t.original_control_number
    and t.control_number <> t.original_control_number
```

Comment: is there any other ways?? what happens when I use an inner join instead of left join?